# Saxon .NET with C++ CLI

Tags: c++, .net, xslt, c++-cli, saxon

I had an idea to use `C++ CLI` to interact with the `Saxon .NET interface` . The problem is that every single example on Saxonica is with `C#` , and not `C++` . can you give me an example that caches an XML file ,  and using Xslt filepaths to transform it using C++ CLI to use the .NET interface ???

Also pls dont give me workarounds that dont use C++ CLI

Comment: Which version of Saxon .NET do you want do that with? What did you try and how did it fail?

Comment: Im just asking for an example , Because there isnt an example using C++ CLI. anyways im using .NET 6.0

Comment: Im getting basic errors  that i can fix if i see an example using CLI

Comment: Well, .NET 6 is .NET Core, the only Saxon version working with .NET Core is SaxonCS? Are you trying to use SaxonCS? Saxon 10 or 9 .NET are working only with the .NET framework.

Comment: Im just asking for an example , I dont know what SaxonCS is

Comment: Well, for .NET 6 you won't find examples using Saxon unless you use SaxonCS, the previous Saxon 9 or 10 .NET releases rely on IKVM and that way work with .NET framework. So whether it is C# or C++ CLI, if you really work with .NET 6 would not even possible to get existing Saxon .NET examples to work with .NET 6, unless you changed from using Saxon .NET to using SaxonCS.

Comment: But as you say you don't even know that product it seems it doesn't make much sense to expect an example, the errors you might have gotten might simply be due to the lack of compatibility of Saxon .NET with .NET 6, independent of whether you would try to use C# or C++ CLI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A minimal sample using Saxon .NET HE 10 (tested with 10.6 initially, now updated to 10.7) run on Windows against .NET framework 4.8 is e.g.

```
#include "pch.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace Saxon::Api;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    Processor^ processor = gcnew Processor();

    Console::WriteLine(processor->ProductVersion);

    DocumentBuilder^ docBuilder = processor->NewDocumentBuilder();

    Uri^ baseUri = gcnew Uri(System::Environment::CurrentDirectory + "\\");

    XdmNode^ inputDoc = docBuilder->Build(gcnew Uri(baseUri, "input-sample1.xml"));

    XsltCompiler^ xsltCompiler = processor->NewXsltCompiler();

    xsltCompiler->BaseUri = baseUri;

    XsltExecutable^ xsltExecutable = xsltCompiler->Compile(gcnew Uri(baseUri, "sheet1.xsl"));

    Xslt30Transformer^ xslt30Transformer = xsltExecutable->Load30();

    xslt30Transformer->ApplyTemplates(inputDoc, processor->NewSerializer(Console::Out));

    return 0;
}
```

Example project at https://github.com/martin-honnen/SaxonHECLIExample1.

To write to a file instead, use e.g.

```
FileStream^ resultStream = File::OpenWrite("result1.xml");

xslt30Transformer->ApplyTemplates(inputDoc, processor->NewSerializer(resultStream));

resultStream->Close();
```

instead of `xslt30Transformer->ApplyTemplates(inputDoc, processor->NewSerializer(Console::Out));`; example adaption is at https://github.com/martin-honnen/SaxonHECLIExample1/tree/WriteToFileInsteadOfConsole

Comment: Nice but which file does the output go to

Comment: The example so far writes to `Console::Out`, to write to a File use e.g. `xslt30Transformer->ApplyTemplates(inputDoc, processor->NewSerializer(File::OpenWrite("result1.xml")));` after declaring `using namespace System::IO;`.

Comment: Nice it works :)